# Flask app is giving proxy error: ENOTFOUND

Tags: flask, gruntjs

Trying to run an Flask project which uses grunt.

Gruntfile.js has following configuration:

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            //hostname: 'localhost',
            hostname: '0.0.0.0',
            livereload: 35728
        },
        proxies: [{
            context: '/api',
            host: 'backend',
            port: 5000,
            changeOrigin: true
        }],
```

app.py has following:

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='9000', debug=True) #host='0.0.0.0'
```

ServerURL has following configuration:

```
.constant('serverURL', 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/api');
```

Client shows this:

```
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:9000
```

But in Client window I receive this:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> Proxy error:  ENOTFOUND
>> Proxy error:  ENOTFOUND
```

Could anyone tell me what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

In the proxies, try changing the host from `backend` to `0.0.0.0`.

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            //hostname: 'localhost',
            hostname: '0.0.0.0',
            livereload: 35728
        },
        proxies: [{
            context: '/api',
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: 5000,
            changeOrigin: true
        }],
```